# bootstrap3 accordion not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I was using the following code to display an accordion since I have upgraded to bootstrap3 the accordion no longer works, I have tried to add a panel div but the accordion seems to work  and then not work I can open each section but when I go back to the first it does not display and none of the others display either?

```
        <div class="row add-top add-bottom-main">
              <div class="panel accordion" id="accordion2">

                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading proxim-bg-one">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                    <span class="accordion-arrow"><img title="proxim" alt="proxim" src="images/next.png"></span>Question
                    </a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading proxim-bg-two">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                    <span class="accordion-arrow"><img title="proxim" alt="proxim" src="images/next.png"></span>Question
                    </a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading proxim-bg-three">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
                    <span class="accordion-arrow"><img title="proxim" alt="proxim" src="images/next.png"></span>Question
                    </a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading proxim-bg-four">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">
                    <span class="accordion-arrow"><img title="proxim" alt="proxim" src="images/next.png"></span>Question
                    </a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The other issue I have is this line used to be hidden

```
<img id="nav-arrow" class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet" src="images/nav-left.png" title="logo" alt="arrow"/>
```

I have updated the code and now it is displayed all the time?

```
<img id="nav-arrow" class="hidden-sm hidden-md" src="images/nav-left.png" title="logo" alt="arrow">
```

am I missing something here?

thanks

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3 the accordion markup is no longer supported.

But you can still get an accordion effect using the collapse functionality.  There is an accordion example here.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Here is an example with your code.

http://www.bootply.com/94409#

As far as your last issue, it looks like bootStrap 3 has new helper classes.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

`hidden-xs` applies to phones and `hidden-sm` applies to tablets.

So:

```
<img id="nav-arrow" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" src="images/nav-left.png" title="logo" alt="arrow">
```